# Simple user interface on Ubuntu to view and edit a table in a MySQL database

Tags: mysql, user-interface

I've been searching for a while now to find a simple way to display a small table in a MySQL database to a user in Ubuntu and allow them to edit rows in the table. Basically, I'm looking for Microsoft Access for MySQL - create a form, allow the user to enter data and submit it, and click a button to see what's already there in the table. Security isn't important, because it's for a demo. If it can be made to look nice, all the better.

So far all I can find is "write a web app in Django/Drupal/Meteor/some other web framework", which I can do, but I don't want to spend a week on this. But surely there must be some simple app out there that does this?

Answer (score 1):

**[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)** allows for on-screen editing (in grids) of tables and is available for Ubuntu

e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/phpmyadmin.html

I have seen this recommended (but not used it) **[Form Tools](https://formtools.org/)**  (open source)

If you want "more sophistication" regarding "forms" then you may want to look for a "framework" so you can roll your own html forms.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used phpPgAdmin, so I'm guessing that phpMyAdmin is very similar, and I'll have a look at it for now. I really don't want to have to roll my own solution with Flask or Django, or some other framework (although I can) because it's time consuming. I assumed that given the ubiquity of MySQL databases there'd be a simple drag-and-drop interface designer for a quick and dirty database demo, but it appears that's not the case...